# Vertical scrolling issues with Hammer.js

Tags: ios, scroll, safari

I'm having an issue with Hammerjs swipe gestures breaking scrolling on my page. If I enable hammer on my main container with a swipe it breaks the scrolling on iOS devices. However the swipe even does go through and calls the proper function.

Anyone else encountered an issue like this? The tips n tricks section on their site says to avoid vertical swiping and panning but I just wanted to see if there were any workarounds.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50846709/hammerjs-swipe-with-mat-tabs-blocking-vertical-scroll/55494732#55494732 may be this is helpful

Answer (score 1):

When I tried this

```
var myElement = document;

// create a simple instance
// by default, it only adds horizontal recognizers
var mc = new Hammer(myElement);

// let the pan gesture support all directions.
// this will block the vertical scrolling on a touch-device while on the element
mc.get('swipe').set({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL });

// listen to events...
mc.on("swipedown swipeleft swipeup swiperight tap press", function(ev) {
    console.log(ev.type +" gesture detected.");
});
```

Even the comments say,

```
this will block the vertical scrolling on a touch-device while on the element
```

Basically, if you take over the events for vertical swipe, it takes away vertical scrolling on the given element... which in my case is "document", thus disabling scrolling completely... -_-